reporting complicated sentences

I was playing when she came

When I came she gave me a hug

I was playing when she was cooking


How do I report such complicated sentences?

He said he had been palying when she had come or he had been playing when she came

He said when he had come she had given him a hug or when he had come she gave him a hug

He said he had beem playing when had been cooking


Is any version correct?

Your question contains careless errors - 'palying' - 'beem' and omission of 'she'.

What is complicated about those sentences?


He said that he was playing when she arrived OR He said that he had been playing when she arrived.

Arrived is more idiomatic than came in this context. A second past perfect is not necessary to make the meaning clear.

He said that when he arrived she gave him a hug OR He said that when he arrived she had given him a hug.

He said that he had been playing while she was cooking.


I can't quote any 'rule' - those are what feels natural to me as a native speaker.
